# SqlTableDependency for Oracle DB?

Tags: oracle, signalr, razor-pages

I am at a bit of an impasse with a task I've been trying to solve for the past couple of days. I need to monitor an Oracle database table for any new records being added, and when they are I need to update the information displayed on a page without refreshing.

I tried setting up a background service which would keep a collection with the current notifications on display, call a method to get a new list of notifications from the DB and then do a comparison if new ones have been added since the last check. However, the problem I came upon from the very start is that depending on who is the currently logged in user, they may have access to different notifications - users are part of a team and the notifications are visible for every member of said team but not for members of other teams.

In the CodeBehind of the Razor page I am passing the user team ID after getting it through the user ID from the user claims:

```
string userRole = HttpContext.User.GetRole();

if (userRole == "Admin")
{
    LatestNotifications = notificationService.GetLatest(10);
}
else
{
    int userId = HttpContext.User.GetId();
    int teamId = teamService.GetIdByUser(userId);

    LatestNotifications = notificationService.GetLatest(10, teamId);
}
```

But I am not sure how to pass that team ID to the background service. My idea was also to somehow have the background service return the list with the up-to-date notifications back to the page while the page periodically requests that list, and eventually I ended up abandoning that approach because I wasn't able to find enough information whether it is even the correct one.

Then I stumbled on a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dzFk5C7CESo) in which SqlTableDependency is used for listening to the database, while SignalR is used for updating the information on the page. As far as I was able to tell SqlTableDepedency only works for Microsoft SQL Server, thus would not work with the Oracle database that I am using.

So I guess my question is, how to do what SqlTableDependency does but on an Oracle database? Or if that's not possible, what is the correct approach for listening to an Oracle database and do I combine that with SignalR or with something else? I am using DBeaver too, not sure if that makes a difference but figured I'd add it just in case. I'll be extremely thankful for any advice or guidance.